# NPAPI mozilla plugin not loading in linux

Tags: plugins, mozilla, npapi

I have successfully compiled and created npapi so in Linux based on Mozilla npruntime project.
after Building i placed the so file in /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins and set the permission to 644 (similar to other existing plug-ins).

But when i do about:plugins in browser address bar, its not showing my plug-ins (showing only already existing plug-ins.)

Can some help me why Mozilla is not able to register this plug-in. Linux and browser both are 32 bit.

Comment: I'd try loading firefox in debug mode (I believe it is firefox -g) and see if there are any console messages

Comment: Also: try adding logging to your plugin to see if any of its public functions are called at all.